# spring-retry Retryble annotation versus retryTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-retry

I am trying to understand spring-retry and I saw 2 approaches where the first one was the simple

```
    @Retryable(value = {SomeException1.class,SomeException2.class}, maxAttempts = Constants.RETRY_VAL, backoff = @Backoff(value = Constants.RETRY_BACK))
    public String getData(){...}
```

and the second-way RetryTemplate (Execute with RetryCallback/RecoveryCallback).

My understanding is that the second one gives more fine-grained control. When would we go for the 2'nd approach? Would it be when we have our own Implementations for Backoff and retryPolicies?

Also, I couldn't find examples or samples of setting up custom policies up with the `@Retryble` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the second approach `RetryTemplate` is preferred choice. Because this approach help us to write configuration at one place and use at many place.

You can also create one or many `RetryTemplate` beans. Each `RetryTemplate` bean is used for a map of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially equal control either way.

To use a customized `RetryTemplate` via `Retryable`, simply wire up a retry interceptor as a bean (with the custom template) and provide it in the `interceptor` property.

```
/**
 * Retry interceptor bean name to be applied for retryable method. Is mutually
 * exclusive with other attributes.
 * @return the retry interceptor bean name
 */
String interceptor() default "";
```

It's simply a matter of preference which way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  For those who found it a bit cryptic:
To get the effect of a predefined retryTeplate using annotations you can use use something like
" @Retryable(interceptor = "infiniteRetriesWithBackoff")" on your method, 
and in your  in your config class use a RetryInterceptorBuilder to implement a bean named  "infiniteRetriesWithBackoff"

Comment: What about Spring native compile? The annotation approach will also work?